# Difference between "cargo build" and "anchor build"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, solana, anchor-solana, solana-cli

I am following rust tutorials online, and I found that some websites are using `cargo build` command while others are using `anchor build` command to build the project.

What is the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cargo` is Rust's build manager.

`Anchor` is a framework specifically for solana/rust. It has extra features for a better development experience. It is similar to `truffle` framework for Ethereum.

[What Anchor does for you](https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/build-a-blog-dapp-using-anchor)

> Building Solana programs in Rust language can be tough. Anytime you
> want to save or retrieve data from an account, you need to think about
> packing/unpacking the data, serializing/unserializing the data and
> formats, which are all a real pain.

> Anchor abstracts away from the low
> level construction of accounts, the packing and unpacking, and
> modifying the interfaces to your Solana program. It does this by
> bundling the boilerplate into rust macros! This gives users of Anchor
> a lot of shortcuts and speed to building Solana programs. There are
> always two parts to a Solana app -- the on-chain program and accounts,
> and the off-chain app that interacts with it.

> The other benefit Anchor
> brings is the alignments of the interaction between these two app
> segments. This alignment is called an Interface Description Language
> (IDL). Since the interface of the off-chain app (say, in JavaScript)
> must always match the on-chain Solana program, this is a really nice
> convenience feature to have.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, `anchor build` does `cargo build-bpf` and then extracts the program's IDL at `src/lib.rs`.

`cargo build-bpf` (now `cargo build-sbf`) differs from `cargo build` because it specifically builds a Solana on-chain program, and not a general binary / library that can be used on your system.

And the IDL is an important feature of Anchor -- it exposes the program's interface to be consumed by any client.